# Как сделать падение обьектов по нажатию кнопки в 2D кликере?

Tags: c#, unity3d-android, unity3d

Хочу сделать в игре при нажатии кнопки лавину монет, чтобы они падали сверху вниз. Не совсем понимаю, как такое реализовать на C# в Unity...
Мне нужно:

1. Создание объектов монеток
2. Включение физики при нажатии на кнопку
3. Удаление объектов, когда они доходят до определенной позиции

Comment: Для начала попробуйте создать одну монетку, затем попробуйте сделать так, чтобы она перемещалась как вам нужно, затем реализуйте удаление при столкновении с дном того, куда она падает (вы же знаете, как работают коллайдеры?), затем реализуйте удаление при тыке в экран, сначала в любое место, затем так, чтобы только при тыке в саму монетку. Затем всё что получилось генерируйте в цикле по рандомным координатам верхушки экрана в любых нужных количествах. Готово. Это я вам советую как человек, который совершенно ничего не знает про Unity. Так что мы с вами в равных условиях.

Comment: @Serik Если мой ответ вам помог, пожалуйста, примите его, нажав на галочку. Если у вас остались вопросы - задавайте их:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Создание объекта - [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)
2. Связано: [Префабы](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/Prefabs.html)
3. Физика тела: [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html)
4. Для включение компонента можно использовать: [enabled](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html)
5. Обработка вхождения в [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html)
6. Уничтожение объекта: [Destroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html)

Comment: только я бы, наверное, все же акуратно в кликере инстанциировал обьекты - уж слишком много может приходиться создавать. Вполне возможно в даном случае лучше сделать оптимизацию - создавать новый обьект только по мере необходимости. В ином случае - по триггеру перемещать на область над экраном. В таком случае и дестрой не нужен. По поводу остального - все хорошо, с меня плюс.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы. Я представляю эту лавину: монет 50 там точно должно быть! Однако я отвечал на конкретный запрос: `Создание объектов монеток`

Comment: извините,но я не совсем как реализовать создание монеток... создаются у меня допустим 30 обьектов монеток,но они пусты,хотя материал и прочее на них висят,В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @Serik Возможно, вам лучше задать отдельный вопрос насчет того, почему уже созданные монекты с висящими на них нужными компонентами не отоброажаются.

Comment: @Serik Вопрос, заданный вами, звучит так: как создать монетки. Если у вас на самом деле вопрос: почему уже созданные монетки не отображаются, вам стоит задать другой вопрос. Этот - либо закрыть, приняв ответ, либо (возможно даже лучше с какой-то стороны) удалить.